# BeautifulSoup empty array as result

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am new with beautifulSoup and I would like to know why when I try to retrieve the prices of the boats of [this](https://www.moorings.co.uk/destinations/americas/brazil/paraty-sailing-holidays#!date=2020-8-1&departureId=5422461&yachtId=91&price=3444&sortOrder=Price%20low%20to%20high&showAllDepartures=false&hullType=All&length=All&yachtClass=All&numberOfCabins=All&numberOfDays=7&numberOfPassengers=2&numberOfToilets=All&numberOfShowers=All&productType=1) website it is returning an empty array ?

Here is my code :

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

source = requests.get('https://www.moorings.co.uk/destinations/americas/brazil/paraty-sailing-holidays#!date=2020-8-1&departureId=5422461&yachtId=91&price=3444&sortOrder=Price%20low%20to%20high&showAllDepartures=false&hullType=All&length=All&yachtClass=All&numberOfCabins=All&numberOfDays=7&numberOfPassengers=2&numberOfToilets=All&numberOfShowers=All&productType=1')
page_soup = BeautifulSoup(source.text, 'html.parser')
pages = page_soup.find_all("h4", {"class":"text-align-left"})

print(len(pages))
print(pages)
```

It is returning an empty array so length = 0

Please tell me what I am doing wrong ...

If it is not possible, is it possible to retrieve the text of Crtl-Shift-I using python of a website ??

Comment: Looks like the website doesn't load the boat prices immediately, and in fact it's incredibly slow at loading too. You can't use beautifulsoup on a website which's contents are dynamically loaded, look into using selenium or a similar library

Comment: Showing your desired output would make it easier to answer.

Comment: Ok thank you what would you recommend other than selenium ?

Comment: @HumayunAhmadRajib my desired output is to have an array with the prices of the boat which are on the page

Answer (score 0):

Since the content is loaded dynamically you cannot directly use beautifulsoup.
You'll have to interpret the html/javascript first which causes to update the dom with the actually information about the boats.

For example you could use selenium.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:\\Users\\kuehn\\Downloads\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver")
driver.get('https://www.moorings.co.uk/destinations/americas/brazil/paraty-sailing-holidays#!date=2020-8-1&departureId=5422461&yachtId=91&price=3444&sortOrder=Price%20low%20to%20high&showAllDepartures=false&hullType=All&length=All&yachtClass=All&numberOfCabins=All&numberOfDays=7&numberOfPassengers=2&numberOfToilets=All&numberOfShowers=All&productType=1')
html = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, features='lxml')

for tag in soup.find_all("h4", {"class":"text-align-left"}):
    print(tag.text)
```

The result for me was then

PS C:\stackoverflow\beautiful_soup> python .\main.py

DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:53420/devtools/browser/d86a7c8b-d960-4b45-8849-2d09b7bbebda

Moorings 413 - 3 Cabin Monohull

Moorings 419 - 3 Cabin Monohull

Moorings 45 - 3 Cabin Monohull

Moorings 51.4 - 4 Cabin Monohull

Moorings 413 - 3 Cabin Monohulledit